# Wrong argument type for _countDownTimer.onComplete

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am trying to implement a countdown timer from GitHub, but I am getting the error as shown in the screenshot. The error message is quite clear, but I fail to see how I can fix it... I added two screenshots that will perhaps clarify more than just the code. Does any of you have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Error message]

[image: CountDownTimer class]

```dart
CountDownTimer _countDownTimer = CountDownTimer(
      duration: kWorkDuration,
      fillColor: Colors.pink,
      onComplete: () {
        setState(() async {
          widget.timesCompleted[indexTimesCompleted] = Icon(
            Icons.brightness_1_rounded,
            color: Colors.pink,
            size: 5.0,
          );
          indexTimesCompleted++;
          await NDialog(
            dialogStyle: DialogStyle(titleDivider: true),
            title: Text("Timer Completed"),
            content: Text("Time to break."),
            actions: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                        (states) => Colors.green),
                  ),
                  child: Text("Start a short break"),
                  onPressed: () {}),
            ],
          ).show(context);
        });
      },
    );

    CircularCountDownTimer clock = CircularCountDownTimer(
      controller: _clockController,
      isReverseAnimation: true,
      ringColor: Color(0xff0B0C19),
      height: height,
      width: width,
      autoStart: false,
      duration: _countDownTimer.duration * 60,
      isReverse: true,
      textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      fillColor: _countDownTimer.fillColor,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2A2B4D),
      strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
      onComplete: _countDownTimer.onComplete, //This is the faulty line
    );
```

Comment: is `CountDownTimer` a class you wrote? If it is, could you try changing `final Function onComplete` to `final VoidCallback onComplete` to see if that helps solve the issue?

Comment: @h8moss It totally worked, thanks a lot! I just can't find the button to pin your comment as the answer somehow...

Comment: Happy to help! I posted my comment as an answer if you want to mark that as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you declared `on complete` as any function instead of as a void function with no arguments. To fix it, change this line:

```
final Function onComplete;
```

to this:

```
final VoidCallback onComplete;
```